# Change folder color in IntelliJ based on it's content

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, directory, ide, intellij-plugin

**My goal:** I want to change the color of the folders in IntelliJ based on the file contents inside it. We have folders that contain a certain file, let's call it target.json, and every folder that contains this file should be marked in some way so it's quickly visible, which folder contains this.

**What I tried:** I tried doing this via scopes and file colors, however, I could only manage to highlight the single file, not the parent folder. I looked at writing a plugin, however, I never did that and don't know if that's the proper approach.

Comment: I don't know if this is helping or not: There is a plugin in IntelliJ named "Atom Material Icons" that can change your folder icons and colors. I have used it for years, and it helps me a lot.